# How to make if client don't attach name property got fail 400 response and no push data

Tags: javascript

please help me

I want to make if client input without name property then rejected to submit and get respon fail 400.

then if client input name property it got success respond 201 and push the data

I've tried with this code, the respond is right but it keep submit/push the data even if fail (no input name property)

```
const addNoteHandler = (request, h) => {
    const { name, year, author, summary, publisher, pageCount, readPage, reading } = request.payload;
    const id = nanoid(16);
    const createdAt = new Date().toISOString();
    const updatedAt = createdAt;
    const newNote = {
      name, year, author, summary, publisher, pageCount, readPage, reading, id, createdAt, updatedAt,
      };
      notes.push(newNote);    
      
     const isSuccess = notes.filter((note) => note.id === id).length > 0;
     
      if (name === undefined && name === null) {
      const response = h.response({
        status: 'fail',
        message: 'Gagal menambahkan buku, mohon isi nama buku',
      });
      response.code(400);
      return response;
    } if (isSuccess) {
      const response = h.response({
        status: 'success',
        message: 'Buku berhasil ditambahkan',
        data: {
          bookId: id,
        },
      });
      response.code(201);
      return response; 
   }
   
};
```

Comment: Use `||` operator instead `&&`

Comment: Or you can just use not operator if (!name)...

Comment: I've tried with that code, the respond is right but it keep submit/push the data even if fail (no input name property)

Comment: `else if (isSuccess) {}`